# How to decode ASCII characters from Swift String

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble decoding a string with Swift.

The string value is `Niks \u013beo\u0146enko`, but I want to decode it to say `Niks Ļeoņenko`.

I'm new to Swift, so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode the string using the String encoding type of `.nonLossyASCII`.

```swift
let name = "Niks \\u013beo\\u0146enko"

if let name_data = name.data(using: .utf8),
  let decodedString = String(data: name_data, encoding: .nonLossyASCII)
{
  print("Result: \(decodedString).")  // Prints "Niks Ļeoņenko"
} else {
  print("There was a problem decoding the string.")
}
```